# ASIFormDataRequest responseString return nscfstring or nscfconstant string

Tags: iphone, objective-c, web-services, nsstring, asihttprequest

I am using `ASIFormDataRequest` to call a `web service` with video file. it workes fine if video is small but if video is about 30 seconds or above then its response return as `__NSCFString` or sometime `__NSCFConstantString`

my code is as below.

```
__block ASIFormDataRequest *request=[[ASIFormDataRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:APP_APIURL]];

    [request setPostValue:strVal forKey:@"jsonRequest"];
    if (videoData) {
        [request setData:videoData withFileName:videoName andContentType:nil forKey:@"videoFile"];
    }

    [request startSynchronous];
    request.timeOutSeconds=999999999;
    // response 
    NSString *strResponse=[request responseString];

if (strResponse) {
    SBJsonParser *parser=[[SBJsonParser alloc] init];
    NSMutableDictionary *dicData=[[parser objectWithString:strResponse] valueForKey:@"uploadVideo"];
```

Please help me to solve this issue.

Shivam

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what is the problem... __NSCFString and __NSCFConstantString are still NSString objects.

Comment: I just updated my post... if it returns __NSCFString and __NSCFConstantString  Then json parser cant parse it.

Answer (score 0):

Here are few solutions to your problem:

- Use introspection and check the returned object for it's class. If you're getting a "constant" string, probably it's not what you're expecting. Print it or check it's contents.
- If you're receiving a video file - use [request responseData] or better, use the file saving techniques described in ASIHTTPRequest library. How can you download a file and parse json response at the same time?
- Use [JSONKit](https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit) - IMHO the fastest json parser.

Comment: Thansk for your reply but I dont think this is the issue of json parser.  Because NSString *strResponse=[request responseString]; should return nsstring but it returns __NSCFString or __NSCFConstantString

Comment: It may be issue due to..... I am calling this function on secondary thread. using MBProgressHUD

Comment: Well, the last advice is not a direct solution, just a recommendation. Try running the requests on the main thread, but I don't see any reason - no UI stuff there and ASIHTTPRequest always calls main thread when needed. You could use ASI's asynchronous requests or queue.